# Count rows since last occurrence of value , excluding blank cells from the count

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to count the number of rows since the last occurrence of a specific value, while excluding rows where the cell is a blank or empty value. I have provided a sample of fake data to try to explain what I'm asking. So, with the sample data, on every occurrence of "Apple", I would like to show the number of valued rows since the last occurrence of "Apple". I currently have a formula like this:

`=ROW()-MAX(FILTER(ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1)),INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()-1)=INDIRECT("B"&ROW())))`

The formula gives me the number of rows since the last occurrence, but does not exclude the blank cells, and I'm wanting to figure out a way to get this result without counting the rows with blank cells in the column.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHWJz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming values are in range A2:A and we want the results in column B, use this formula in cell B2 and then manually extend down:

```
=IF(A2="Apple",IFERROR(MATCH("Apple",QUERY({A$2:A2,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A$2:A2))},"select Col1 where Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc offset 1"),0),0),)
```

### Explanation

The `QUERY` retrieves all values above the current one (e.g. for row 7 it will be A2:A6) in reverse order (A6, A5, ..., A2) and *excluding blanks*.

`MATCH` returns the position of the first occurrence of the value in interest in the result of the `QUERY`.

I was not able easily to make this formula auto-extend using `ARRAYFORMULA` or `MAP(LAMBDA)`, so it has to be manually extended.